# What does "Policymakers have effectively crossed the Rubicon with respect to Modern Monetary Theory (MMT)" mean?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

i know what does "cross Rubicon" means, and in my understanding this sentence means "policymakers now have nothing to do but to follow MMT". Am I right?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what your question is. You know the meaning of the expression. Why do you suppose it would mean something differently here?

Answer (score 1):

"[Crossing the Rubicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Rubicon_(disambiguation))" is a common expression for "passing the point of no return".